# IBM Webshpere Application Server map role to user with java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere

Here I have specified security roles for my application

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>visitor</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
    ....
    <auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

With WAS admin console I can map role to user, but the question is *Can I do this with java code* ?

I new with this, so maybe the answer is obvious, but I will appreciate any help

Comment: You can execute `wsadmin` from your java code, just like a command execution, which will let you do this.